# python qt4 isn't working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, windows-7-x64

I have watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOuCuLHmk3o) and then i created succesfully hello.py. But i run hello.py , doesn't show a form. I need to help. I haven't taken any error ever.
After I have created interface in qt designer,i created hello.py script. "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4.bat" hello.ui -o hello.py
The codes is below :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(509, 312)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.label.clear)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textChanged(QString)")), self.label.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.lineEdit.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Hello World", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton", None))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate your object and set it up. Adding this at the bottom of your current code will show the form.

```
import sys

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    def execute_event(self):
        pass
    def execute_all_event(self):
        pass
    def reload_event(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This answer was from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159003/creating-simple-form-with-qt-designer-and-pyqt).