# Qt Python conversion GUI

Tags: python, qt, combobox

I prepared a form use to QT and conversion to Python:

```
Form = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()

ui.setupUi(Form)


Form.show()

print  ui.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'll write the code, the contents of the list, I want to use. But how?

Comment: can you explain more about what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is incorrect this is a example of form in `pyqt` :

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            self.ui = Ui_Form()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
        def execute_event(self):
            pass
        def execute_all_event(self):
            pass
        def reload_event(self):
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        myapp = MyForm()
        myapp.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159003/creating-simple-form-with-qt-designer-and-pyqt) link !